# Querying across relationships with LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is what my model looks like:
[image]

I'm trying to get the count of distinct Assesors by a certain EventId.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
var x = db.Assessors.Select(a => (a.Assessments.Select(y => y.EventFacility.EventId == 138))).Count();
```

Unfortunately, I must be coding this wrong because instead of getting the expected result (a count of 9, in this case) I'm getting the wrong result: 35.

I'm wondering if someone can take a look at my LINQ statement and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do your entity classes look like?

Comment: The Entity classes are database-first.  They are just as the image shows, although the image is only showing the relevant ID fields needed.  Each ID is a foreign key in the each related table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Where` and `Any` like this:

```
var result = db.Assessors
            .Where(a => a.Assessments.Any(y => y.EventFacility.EventId == 138));
```

What this is saying is that you want all Assessors that are parents of any Assessment that is related to that particular Event.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I apparently was overthinking how this was supposed to work.  Your code and explanation are much appreciated!  As soon as the time is up, I'll mark the answer.

Comment: I should add that I had to use 'DistinctBy' and 'Count' to get the distinct Assessors and how many there were.  Again, my thanks.

Comment: Is `DistinctBy` really needed? Did you test without it?

Comment: No, I added it, but I'll test without and let you know my results.

Comment: You are correct, Yacoub.  The DistinctBy is not needed.  Again, much thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this backward, start from what you know (the event since you have it's ID) and navigate to what you want through the navigation properties.

It's impossible to tell from your schema as it includes neither the properties nor the mapping type 1:1? 1:N? Can't know from simple lines

It would probably look Something like this

```
var x = db.Events
           .Where(ev=>ev.Id == 138)
           .SelectMany(ev=>ev.EventFacilities) //(i'm assumine possibly multiple and not 1 per event, once again schema doesn't show it, if it's not the case change SelectMany to Select)
           .SelectMany(ef=>ef.Assesments) // Same assumption as above
           .Select(as=>as.Assessor) // Asuming otherwise here, if wrong change Select to SelectMany
           .Distinct(); // Ignore duplicate assessors
```

Note that your question is impossible to answer as is, this is a best effort but if you want help you should give "all" the information required, not strip out what doesn't immediately seem relevant, it would've been much easier if you took an actual screenshot of your entity diagram instead of what you made up.